# Invalid resource attribute MySecretA for resource SecretsManager, how to create more than one secret in yml?

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

After deploying my project in cloud formation attemping to create more than one secret, the following error message is displayed:

`Invalid resource attribute MySecretA for resource SecretsManager`

YAML snippet:

```
SecretsManager:
 Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
 MySecretA:
   Properties:
     Description: "some description"
     Name: "password B"
 MySecretB:
   Properties:
     Description: "another decription"
     Name: "password A"
```

I did it based on this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html. Would you know how to create multiple secrets in the same yaml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```yaml
 MySecretA:
   Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
   Properties:
     Description: "some description"
     Name: "password B"

 MySecretB:
   Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
   Properties:
     Description: "another decription"
     Name: "password A"
```

Comment: Worked! but one thingy, can I replace MySecretA/B with anything I want?

Comment: [Logical ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html) doesn't have to be `MySecretA/B`, just chose those to be the same as your example